# Console.SetOut to StreamWriter, write to textfile constantly

Tags: c#, logging, streamwriter, console.out.writeline, console.setout

I'm using the Console.SetOut method to write all my Console.Out.WriteLines to a file, and this works. The only problem is that it only writes everything to the textfile when I close my application instead of it writing whenever a Console.Out.WriteLine happens. 
Any ideas on how I can realise this?

How I do it:
Before Application.Run();

```
FileStream writerOutput = new FileStream("Logging_Admin.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writerOutput);
Console.SetOut(writer);
```

After Application.Run():

```
writer.Dispose();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `StreamWriter` will buffer its contents by default.  If you want to flush the buffer you must call the [`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) method:

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

Comment: Yep that's the way to go. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

StreamWriter has an AutoFlush property. When set to true, you should get the result you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call flush every time manually, you might want to consider implementing your own TextWriter-derived object to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

To flush the buffer, you can do 
    writer.Close();